# Using an HTML file as string in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, file-io, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension and I want to use an HTML as a big string, I don't want to maintain it in the JavaScript file.

What's the best practice to do that? Is there anyway to read this HTML (that I ship in my extension package) file as string?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want....

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', chrome.extension.getURL('somePage.html'), false);
request.send(null);  

if (request.status === 200) {  
  alert(request.responseText);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.documentElement.outerHTML` will give you the whole HTML of the page.
`document.body.outerHTML` gives the HTML of the `BODY`-element only.